POPSQL Table not showing all of its content why is that?
It's just showing the first row of the table only!
enter image description here
I tried looking online but didn't find any help
POPSQL Table not showing all of its content why is that? I already entered my database and everything?
Every time I run it only shows the first row

Odd. Which dbms are you using?

Run SELECT COUNT(*) AS ROW_COUNT to see how many rows are in the table, maybe that is all the data there is?
Could be a security issue where your access is only for a certain number of rows. Check your access.
In your image, you aren't showing us the actual data in the table, only the DDL.
